# Django interactive html form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I started using the Django today, and tried building a html form

the code for views.py is

```
def home(request): 
    t = get_template('home.html')
    html = t.render(Context({ "GetLabel": 'Welcome to the SPACE program.',
                              "GetInput": '',
                              "Next": './get_machine' }))
    return HttpResponse(html)     

def get_machine(request):
    t = get_template('home.html')
    html = t.render(Context({ "GetLabel": 'Enter the name of the machine: ',
                              "GetInput": '<input type="text" name="machine_name">',
                              "Next": './get_beamlines'}))
    return HttpResponse(html)

def get_beamlines(request):
    machine_name = request.POST["machine_name"] 
    Context({ "GetLabel": 'Machine already installed<br> Overwrite Existing file',
                  "GetInput": '<select name="check" >  <option value="Yes">Yes</option>    <option value="No">No</option> </select>',
                  "Next": './get_beamline' })
    t = get_template('home.html')
    html = t.render(Context({"GetLabel": 'Enter the number of beamlines: ',
                             "GetInput": '<input type="text" name="beamline_no"',
                             "Key":'Machine Name: ',
                             "Value": machine_name,
                             "Next": './get_beamline_name'}))
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

It goes like this; Now I don't know how to proceed further to get the name of the beamlines(if more than 1)

I'm a novice to django, please correct me if I am wrong.

Is there any other better way of doing the same.

Note: finally, I want to write all the user inputs to an xml file.
I have done the same with the normal python program, by getting the user inputs form raw_imput()

Comment: Have you followed the tutorial? The tutorial covers this in detail :)

Comment: It looks like you are doing alot of stuff in wrong places. 1 - you are templating in views, while you could leave it to templates engine. 2 - you are creating forms manually, while django has excellent forms supprt via Form object. I would solve this problem like this - create form for saving machine information. Then i would override form save method and instead using django ORM to save the info you could do your own XML saving if you really have to...

Comment: @Zayatzz Sorry, I just started django today, I don't know about the django Form object, can you please help me on how to do the same with the django Form object... thanks a lot!

Comment: Check out Michals answer - it has link to forms framework. Also i suggest you go through the tutorial. Its really good tutorial and when i started with Django it helped me ALOT. I still sometimes go back and watch certain parts of it even though i have used django for like 3 years now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some basics about forms are covered in [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial04/), you might also want to use [forms framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/) available within Django.

Comment: I tried the tutorial, but it shows the error cannot import render, I use eclipse with pylint, it also shows no name render in django.shortcuts module, i checked the module render is not there, what shall i do now.

Comment: You mean render_to_response?

Comment: No, just render is not available, so now i use render_to_response. I have proceeded and stuck at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399435/using-formset-factory-in-django

Comment: @ThirumugamS If Michal's answer was of some help to you, make sure to accept his answer.